# Add or Delete Css class when input value is null or notnull

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I want to add/delete css class for some inputs from form

```
<form id="FormId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"validate input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"validate input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"input-bg">​
<input type=​"text" class=​"bg-datepicker">​
</form>

$("#FormId input[type=text]").each(function () 
{
 <!--if input have class validate I want to verify if text !=''-->
input.addClass('error');
<!--else-->
input.removeClass('error');
})
```

how verify here value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use `.filter()`

```
$("#FormId input[type=text].validate").filter(function(){
         this.value ==''?$(this).addClass('error'): $(this).removeClass('error')
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTdu/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#FormId input[type=text]").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('validate')) {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $(this).addClass('error');
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
            $(this).removeClass('error');
        }
    }
});
```

or

```
$("#FormId input[type=text].validate").each(function () {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).addClass('error');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
});
```

Reference

[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com//)

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the inputs with `validate` class. You can use `toggleClass` to add or remove the `error` class by passing a boolean as the second argument:

```
$('#FormId input[type="text"].validate').each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('error', !$.trim(this.value).length);
});
```

#### [.toggleClass Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVW9m/1/)